# UITextView auto layout height when using exclusion path

Tags: ios, uitextview, nslayoutconstraint, ios-autolayout, exclusionpath

I have a UITableViewCell containing a UITextView and a UIImageView. The text view has scrolling disabled. The UITableViewCell does use auto layout to calculate its height to fit the content.

[image: view layout screenshot]

If there is more text than in the screenshot I want the text to flow around the image and use the space below it too. Therefore I use exclusion path on the text view. The exclusion Path gets set correctly and the text flows around the image.

**Exclusion paths must be set after auto layout has calculated the frames**. As the exclusion path blocks some view space on the text view **the containing text does not fit any more** in the height auto layout calculated for the text view.

How can I make this work together with auto layout?

I tried to set a height constraint on the text view after setting exclusion paths:

```
    let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
    textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
```

This does not help. I need to call `layoutSubviews()` on the UITableViewCell to force it to recalculate its height. However this will create an endless loop as I set my exclusion paths in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()`.

Comment: There is a special function of UIView which updates constraints. Maybe try overriding it like this:

    `override func updateConstraints() {
        super.updateConstraints()
        let size = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: textView.frame.size.width, height: CGFloat(MAXFLOAT)))
        textView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: size.height).isActive = true
    }`

Answer (score 0):

I found that `UITextView` does NOT recalculate `intrinsicContentSize` when `isScrollEnabled` is `false` and `textContainer.exclusionPaths` changes.

The solution was simple:

```
class FixedTextView : UITextView {
    
    func setExclusionPaths(_ paths: [UIBezierPath]) {
        textContainer.exclusionPaths = paths
        
        if !isScrollEnabled {
            invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue where I couldn't feasibly access viewDidLayoutSubviews() without a lot of excessive coupling, so I feel your pain.

Suppose you have view A and the subviews include a UITextView.

In view A, override layoutSubviews()

```
override public func layoutSubviews() {
  super.layoutSubviews()
  // At this point, UITextView is laid out and has a valid frame.
  // Set exclusion paths here, now that you have enough info to set coordinates.
  super.layoutSubviews() // do it again.
}
```

This is similar to the approach taken with UILabel and maxPreferredWidth on prior iOS versions. 
[iOS: Multi-line UILabel in Auto Layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12789013/ios-multi-line-uilabel-in-auto-layout)

One caveat: I don't know that setting a constraint in here will help you, as the layout cycles don't really work that way, but according to this [Update Constraints of Cell Subview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31239220/update-constraints-of-cell-subview) , you might be able to get away with doing layoutIfNeeded().

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622482-layoutsubviews   `You should not call this method directly.` You should use `layoutIfNeeded` instead of the second call